# Wathckit pause group animation when ContextMenu is opened

Tags: watchkit

I have the following code which animates the WKInterfaceGroup

```
self.group.setBackgroundImageNamed(String(format: "progress0", currentImage))            
self.group.startAnimatingWithImagesInRange(NSMakeRange(currentImage, 360), duration:remainDuration, repeatCount: 1)
```

I need to pause the animation of the WKInterfaceGroup and then resume it from that point after the menu is dismissed.

I've tried to call `self.group.stopAnimating()` in `didDeactivate()`, but when the menu is dismissed, the animation continues from the point as it was never stopped and I don't understand why.

Is there any other way to pause it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this isn't working is because you can't update interface elements in `didDeactivate`. All updates must happen prior to that call (or during/after a subsequent `willActivate`).

Because of this, and the fact that there is no event fired when a Force Touch menu is displayed, there is no way to stop the animation in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting up/starting the animation in `willActivate`? I ask because `willActivate` is called when you dismiss the force-touch menu, I believe.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the willActivate is called when the Context Menu is dismissed but I'm not starting the animation there. It seems more like stopAnimation does nothing it is is called in didDeactivate.